# Application on remote computer * requested access to the x server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, security, x-server, mobaxterm

Using MobaXtrem to connect from my windows machine to an Ubuntu v16 remote server. I sometimes leave the connection active in the background while I'm away or working on other stuff.

For the second time when I returned to the computer to find a massage on my screen:

An application on remote computer * requested access to the x server.

[Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvtaR.png)

The IPs are of unknown origin and I'm not sure how to start investigating or if I should be worried.

Updade:
I failed to mantion above that I was connected to a self hosted VPN,
It looks like the issue happned while I was connected to the VPN server and it could be an unauthenticated access attempt for exploiting X11 vulnerability.
I have setup IPtables on the server and no popups so far.

I guess that the VPN server forwared the attampt to my computer

Comment: Information related to '117.50.0.0 - 117.50.255.255'

% Abuse contact for '117.50.0.0 - 117.50.255.255' is 'ipas@cnnic.cn'

inetnum:        117.50.0.0 - 117.50.255.255
netname:        UCLOUD-NET
descr:          Shanghai UCloud Information Technology Company Limited
country:        CN
admin-c:        JJ2197-AP

Comment: FYI here is how to lookup who owns a block of IP addresses.   https://www.whatismyip.com/ip-whois-lookup/

Comment: Not so sure what sort of VPN solution you are using, but obviously your internet connection was wide open at the time.    If the person was able to authenticate you would not have seen this message at all.      I am guessing from the fact that this connection attempt was being made to your X Server, and you mentioned IP tables you are using Linux?   Which distribution?

Comment: It was a self hosted openVPN server, running on centOS7, I have replaced this server by now, I do believe that the VPN server forwarded any incoming request to my IP, and in my MobaXtrem client x server was enabled, so it was accepting requests